# How can I get a part of a string from a starting point to the end of the string using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

The title isn't that clear, but I wasn't sure how to phrase it. 
In Ruby,

```
a = "somestring"
a[1] #Becomes 'o'
a[1..4] #Becomes 'omes'
```

This selects a desired portion from a string. 
I was wondering how I should make it so that it selects parts of a string from a fixed starting number to the end of the string, no matter how long it is.

So:

```
a[3 All the way to the end] should become 'estring'
```

I could do `a[1..10000]` but that feels extremely redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `-1` to specify the end of your range - this would point to the last character of a string, no matter the length:

```
a = "This is a string"
a[2..-1]
#=> "is is a string"
```

This same approach can be applied to get the second to last character `-2`, third to last character `-3`, etc.

Hope it helps!